# Creating table in migration InitialCreate.cs

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to create a table inside up function.

```
public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.CrimeReort",
            c => new
                {
                    ImageId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ImageName = c.String(nullable: false),
                    ImageContent = c.Byte[](nullable: false),
                    Createdby=c.String(),
                    CreatedDt=c.DateTime(),
                    Updatedby =c.String(),
                    UpdatedDt=c.DateTime(),
                    flag = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ImageId);

    }
```

I want to declare a byte array byte[] but its giving me an error. Besides that this table has a one-one relationship with another table .I also need to cater that as well. I do not know how to make that relationship in migrations.

Comment: http://tallmaris.com/entity-framework-part-2-migrations-and-relationships/  will show you how to do the relationship.  What error are you getting for the Byte[]?

Comment: it says syntax error; value expected

Comment: use c.Binary() instead of c.Byte[]

Comment: ok and also tell me about the relationship between two tables. How do I mention that in migrations ? Also I want to create a relationship between existing membership tables with my new tables...

Comment: There's an example in the link in my first post.  I added the key line to an answer below with the note about Byte[] as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
AddForeignKey("dbo.CrimeReport", "foreign_Id", "dbo.ForeignTable", "Id");
```

Also use c.Binary() instead of c.Byte[]